# Uncaught (in promise) Promise.then(async) Spring REST

Tags: java, spring, vue.js, rest

Первый раз используя spring REST и vue js. Vue не может найти postmapping, я так понял что это из-за промиса.
[image: JS часть]

[image: Ошибки]

[image: Java часть]

Comment: порт 8082 указан верно?

Comment: да. Указывал server.port = 8082